# 2D Dict with fast Column and Row deletion?

Tags: python, dictionary, 2d, del, two-way

I need a 2D dict like structure that allows fast deletion operation.
F.e.

```
    x['a']['b'] = 1
    x['a']['c'] = 1
    x['a']['d'] = 1
    x['b']['a'] = 1
    x['b']['f'] = 1
    x['e']['b'] = 1
    x['f']['c'] = 1
    ...
```

i.e. the keys a,b,c,e,f,c,... can be used in both dimentions

It is fast to delete by first dimention i.e.

```
   del x[a]
```

but if you want to delete by the second dimension you have to enumerate the elements first, which is slow.

You can also imagine this structure as 2D table where columns and rows have names AND where you can delete Whole row or column fast. At the same time the addition happens one cell at a time.

What would be your solution ?

PS> One possibility would be to keep Lists of keys of 2 to 1 dimensions, but this will take up too  much memory and would keep data for rows/cols which wont be deleted !

---

Will using  Pandas dataframe be faster ?

```
  key1, key2, data
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be impossible without additional memory. As for the second problem, you can in fact store keys for both dimensions and delete when needed. A simple solution using two dictionaries:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Table2D:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._row_to_cols = defaultdict(dict)
        self._col_to_rows = defaultdict(dict)

    def add(self, c, r):
        self._col_to_rows[c][r] = 1
        self._row_to_cols[r][c] = 1

    def get_row(self, r):
        return self._row_to_cols[r]

    def get_col(self, c):
        return self._col_to_rows[c]

    def rem_row(self, r):
        for c in self._row_to_cols[r]:
            del self._col_to_rows[c][r]
        del self._row_to_cols[r]

    def rem_col(self, c):
        for r in self._col_to_rows[c]:
            del self._row_to_cols[r][c]
        del self._col_to_rows[c]

t2d = Table2D()
t2d.add('a', 'c')
t2d.rem_col('a')
print(t2d.get_col('a')
```